# Unable to write to disk via Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to write to a file upon visiting a web page.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$fp = fopen('/tmp/data.txt', 'a') or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Testing whether it's possible to write to a file...\n"; 
fwrite($fp, $txt);
sleep(1);
fclose($fp);
```

I've made sure that `/tmp/data.txt` is owned by `www-data` and has execute permissions, `www-data` runs apache.

I have tried debugging the PHP script using `php <filename>`, and this works perfectly, it's only when I try and visit the webpage does it not work.

I've checked the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` but no error has been reported. The `/tmp/data.txt` file remains empty.

The site is located in the `/var/www/html` directory which is all owned by `www-data` and has the appropriate permissions set.

```
; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
; http://php.net/open-basedir  
;open_basedir =
; be increased on systems where PHP opens many files to reflect the quantity of
; The directory under which PHP opens the script using /~username used only
```

Comment: This should succeed or log an error. Double check the error_reporting and display_errors settings. Keep in mind that Apache often uses a different php.ini than the cli. Also check the open_basedir setting.

Comment: Added the settings you've requested, don't think these are an issue

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your PHP file, run it as a web page and then update your question.

Comment: You are 100% sure that when you visit the webpage **this script** is executed. Are you?